# Perl 6 iterate through command line arguments

Tags: raku

I want to write a Perl 6 program that performs the same operation on an undetermined number of files, just like how you can use `rm file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt` in Linux.

My code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6


my @args = @*ARGS.perl;

for @args -> $arg {
    say $arg
}
```

However, when I invoke it as `./loop_args.pl6 file1.txt file2.txt` I get the following output: `["file1.txt", "file2.txt"]`

What am I doing wrong? I just want it to be an array.

Comment: I would like to know what lead you to use `.perl`, so that we can prevent others from going down this path in the future.

Comment: Hey Brad, I misread the documentation here; I have a bad habit of only looking at the code: http://perl6maven.com/parsing-command-line-arguments-perl6

Comment: Ok. Short of asking Gabor to change that article, I suppose there's not much to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Perl6 the arguments array is `@*ARGS`, this gives the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl6

use v6;

for @*ARGS -> $arg
{
    print("Arg $arg\n");
}
```

So you just need to remove the `.perl` from your `my @args = @*ARGS.perl;` line.

EDIT: Updated as per Ralphs's comments

Comment: You don't need the `use strict;` there :)

Comment: To clarify @Scimon's comment you don't need the `use strict;` because P6 defaults to strict. While I'm writing a comment I'll also note that the `my $arg;` declares *a* `$arg` but it's redundant and misleading. The `-> $arg` declares *another* `$arg` that shadows the `my` one inside the block.

Answer (score 6):

So it depends on what you want to do with the files. If you want to read through them all you might want to take a look at `$*ARGFILES` this is an [IO::CatHandle](https://docs.raku.org/type/IO::CatHandle) Object that batches up all the arguments and treats them as a list of files. So to print them all out you could do.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl6
use v6;

for $*ARGFILES.handles -> $IO {
    $IO.path.say
}
```

Ok so that's a bit more convoluted than looking at @*ARGS. But what if you wanted to print the first 5 lines for each file?

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl6
use v6;

for $*ARGFILES.handles -> $IO {
    say $IO.lines: 5;
}
```

Or maybe you just want to read the contents of all the files and print them out?

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl6
use v6;

.say for $*ARGFILES.lines;
```

Hope that gives you some ideas.